# How to convert string to System.Linq.Expressions.Expression

Tags: c#

I have a grid which shows records from a table. On this grid I am using customized pagination and sorting, so I need to use customized column filtering as well.

```
var expression = ExpressionBuilder.Expression<EventModel>(request.Filters);
```

The above code snippet gets filter condition from Kendo Grid in the controller of type `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<EventModel,bool>>` expression,
and am converting it to string, and passing it to DAL code as shown below,

```
string filterExpression = ExpressionBuilder.Expression<EventModel>(request.Filters).ToString();
List<EventModel> eventModelList = new List<EventModel>();
eventModelList = eventComponent.GetEventData(request.PageSize, request.Page, searchstring, sortDirection, sortColumnName, filterExpression, ref recCount);
```

In the DAL I need to convert `filterExpression` from string to `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<EventModel,bool>>`

[image: Converting to Expression type]

```
var res = eventInfo.AsQueryable().Where(filterExpression);//Gets error here
lstEventInfo = lstEventInfo.AsQueryable().Where(res);
```

Am getting an error can not convert from string to System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>'.
So could anyone tell me how could I convert a string to `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<ModelClass,bool>>` type in C#.

Comment: Why are you converting it to a string in the first place?

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. I want to pass this string type expression to DAL, since I could not find a way to pass 'expression' type directly  to DAL, so I converted 'expression' type to string, and thought to convert it back to 'Expression' type again.

Comment: I have used 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting' to convert to string and casting it back.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example how to create where dynamically.

```
public class Mock
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ForeignId { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list = new List<Mock>()
        {
            new Mock{
                Id  = 1,
                ForeignId = 1,
                Total = 100,
            },
        };

        var query = list.AsQueryable();

        // t
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Mock), "t");

        // t.Total
        var propertyExpression = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "Total");

        // 100.00M
        var constant = Expression.Constant(100M, typeof(decimal));

        // t.Total == 100.00M 
        var equalExpression = Expression.Equal(propertyExpression, constant);

        // t => t.Total == 100.00M
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(equalExpression, parameter);

        // calls where.
        var whereExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Where", new[] { query.ElementType }, query.Expression, lambda);

        // add where to query.
        query = query.Provider.CreateQuery(whereExpression) as IQueryable<Mock>;


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

---

But You can use this

https://github.com/PoweredSoft/DynamicLinq

here is the Nuget package

https://www.nuget.org/packages/PoweredSoft.DynamicLinq/

There is a litle sample here how to do simple web filtering

https://github.com/PoweredSoft/DynamicLinq#how-it-can-be-used-in-a-web-api

You could adapt it to fit your filter expression model.

```
[HttpGet][Route("FindClients")]
    public IHttpActionResult FindClients(string filterField = null, string filterValue = null, 
    string sortProperty = "Id", int? page = null, int pageSize = 50)
    {
        var ctx = new MyDbContext();
        var query = ctx.Clients.AsQueryable();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterField) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(filterValue))
        query = query.Query(t => t.Contains(filterField, filterValue)).OrderBy(sortProperty);

        //  count.
        var clientCount = query.Count();
        int? pages = null;

        if (page.HasValue && pageSize > 0)
        {
        if (clientCount == 0)
            pages = 0;
        else
            pages = clientCount / pageSize + (clientCount % pageSize != 0 ? 1 : 0);
        }

        if (page.HasValue)
        query = query.Skip((page.Value-1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);

        var clients = query.ToList();

        return Ok(new
        {
        total = clientCount,
        pages = pages,
        data = clients
        });
    }
```

---

An alternative is to use DynamicLinq

https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it is complete and filled with clear examples, easy to reproduce. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code snippet for converting from string to Expression.

```
   public List<Product> Get(string filter = null)
    {
        var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Product), "x");

        var e = (Expression)DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, null, filter);

        var typedExpression = (Expression<Func<Product, bool>>)e;

        var res = _productDal.GetList(typedExpression);
        return res;
    }
```

I used **System.Linq.Dynamic.Core** namespace for Asp.Net Core. You can use **System.Linq.Dynamic** namespace for Asp.Net.

If you use classic Asp.Net instead of Asp.Net Core, you should write

`var e = (Expression)DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, null, filter);` instead of

`var e = (Expression)DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, null, filter);`

And your string parameter (which is named as a ***filter***) should be like *"(x.ProductID > 10)"*

If your string parameter is different, you can use following code snippet to convert from expression to string for getting same string parameter into *Get* method.

```
public static string Select(this Grid _grid, Expression<Func<Product, bool>> filter = null)
    {
        //filter = {x => (x.ProductID > 1)}
        BinaryExpression be = filter.Body as BinaryExpression;

        //be = {(x.ProductID > 1)}
        return be.ToString();
    }
```